# How to fetch data from JSON in Kotlin Android

Tags: android, json, parsing, kotlin

I want to fetch some json data, see in the image the green arrow:

[image]

**The problem is that Android Studio doesn't let me get the data I want.  It stops until a step before (I think).  In my adapter class check:**

```
holder?.view?.textWeather?.text = weatherFor.weather.toString()
```

**Also it shows me in the emulator the red arrow, what is this?**

Below is my main Activity's json method with the classes i want to fetch data for, and the associated Adapter class.

**Main Activity**

```
fun fetchJson() {
     val url="https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=Prague,CZ&appid=4cf7f6610d941a1ca7583f50e7e41ba3"
     val request=Request.Builder().url(url).build()
     val client= OkHttpClient()
     client.newCall(request).enqueue(object :Callback {

         override fun onResponse(call: Call?, response: Response?) {
             val body=response?.body()?.string()
             println(body)

             val gson=GsonBuilder().create()

             val forecastfeed=gson.fromJson(body,ForecastFeed::class.java)

             runOnUiThread{
                 recyclerView_main.adapter=MainAdapter(forecastfeed)
             }
         }

         override fun onFailure(call: Call?, e: IOException?) {
             println("Failed to execute request")
         }
     })
}

class ForecastFeed(val list:List<ForecastWeatherList>) { }

class ForecastWeatherList(val weather:List<WeatherData>) { }

class WeatherData(val main:String,val icon:String) { }
```

**Adapter**

```
class MainAdapter(val forecastfeed: ForecastFeed): RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomViewHolder>() {

    val forecastWeather = listOf<String>("First","Second")

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CustomViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val weatherFor = forecastfeed.list.get(position)
        holder?.view?.textWeather?.text = weatherFor.weather.toString()
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CustomViewHolder{
        //how do we even create a view
        val layoutInflater =LayoutInflater.from(parent?.context)
        val cellForRow=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.weather_row,parent,false)
        return CustomViewHolder(cellForRow)
    }    

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return forecastfeed.list.count()
    }
}

class CustomViewHolder(val view: View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) { }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can format the data manually

```
holder?.view?.textWeather?.text = "weather ${weatherFor.weather.map{it.main}.joinToString(", ")}"
```

or use [data classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html)

Comment: I think the OP should not use either manual formatting or data classes, but both of them: `WeatherData` looks like a simple data container, so a `data class` would perfectly fit the use case. Also, I think manual formatting is better than overriding `toString`, since the latter should be used to return "a string representation of the object", not something specific to a specific use case

Comment: it still gives me an error on the "main" word
"Unresolved reference main"

Comment: `weatherFor.weather` is a collection of WeatherData objects, you can iterate over it. for example: `holder?.view?.textWeather?.text ="weather ${weatherFor.weather.map{it.main}.joinToString(", ")}"`

Comment: @akaki Thank you so much!!(If you want edit your post and put the answer you gave me now on it!)

Answer (score 0):

You need to overwrite `WeatherData.toString()` to have a hand on what's displayed.

```
class WeatherData(val main:String,val icon:String) {

    override fun toString(): String {
        return "$main $icon"
    }

}
```

Further more you should use a `RecyclerView` with a `ViewHolder` to handle properties one-by-one and enable more complex layouts. If needed.

Comment: Ok but how can i get only the main or only the icon??